# Angular two way binding (different behavior in IE 9)

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-9, two-way-binding

I am creating an Angular application and utilizing the Angular two way binding method for all of my inputs. The application must be supported for IE versions 9 an above. For the latest versions of IE (10/Edge), the binding works perfectly fine. However, when I tested on IE 9, the binding only works when additions are made to the input, meaning if there is an input and there is a value existent for it and I add to it, the model is updated or the input value reflects the additions made to it. However, when removing or deleting characters from the input, the model doesn't update, or the input value is not changed.

Could someone please explain to me why this would be ? Is this expected behavior for IE 9 ?

Thanks

Comment: With only the above description, we can't debug and locate the issue. Please refer to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You could use online code editor like [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) to show your sample. So that we can have a test and have a better understanding of the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You are, most probably, missing classList polyfill. Make sure to check

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html

Comment: Hi, Gauri. Thanks for providing an answer. So, I npm installed the classList polyfill and uncommented it from the pollyfills.ts file as well. However, sill the issue persists. Do you know if there is some other pollyfill I should include ? Thanks!